# SendAsync email error in MvcMailer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcmailer

when i want send mail Async in my controller with SendAsync method of MvcMailer i get to this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>.
```

i use MVC4.

what is cause of this error?

Comment: The answer is provided here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031144/async-keyword-and-choice-of-the-taskscheduler