# async keyword and choice of the TaskScheduler

Tags: c#, signalr, async-await

I would like to know the reasoning behind the way the compiler choose the TaskScheduler when compiling using the async keyword.

My test method is called by SignalR (ASP.NET host, IIS8, websocket transport) on the OnConnectedAsync method.

```
protected override async Task OnConnectedAsync(IRequest request, string connectionId)
{
   SendUpdates();
}
```

Starting a task on the Current synchronization context will result to an InvalidOperationException in System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted()

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked `<%@ Page Async="true" %>`.

Fine. With this SendUpdates definition, I get the above exception:

```
    private async void SendUpdates()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    await Connection.Broadcast("blabla");
                }
            });

    }
```

But even more interesting is when I don't get the exception. The following works:

```
    private void SendUpdates()
```

And the following works too

```
    private async Task SendUpdates()
```

this last one works too, but it's essentially the same as the above example.

```
    private Task SendUpdates()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    await Connection.Broadcast("blabla");
                }
            });

    }
```

Do you know how the compiler choose which scheduler to use here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the primary guidelines in writing `async` code is "avoid `async void`" - that is, use `async Task` instead of `async void` unless you're implementing an `async` event handler.

`async void` methods use `SynchronizationContext`'s `OperationStarted` and `OperationCompleted`; see my MSDN article [It's All about the SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) for more details.

ASP.NET detects the call to `OperationStarted` and (correctly) rejects it because it's illegal to put an `async` event handler there. When you correct the code to use `async Task`, then ASP.NET no longer sees an `async` event handler.

You may find my [intro to `async` / `await` post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

When you call:

```
private async void SendUpdates()
```

With the call to [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051.aspx) and using the [`async` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) on the anonymous delegate, you aren't actually providing a continuation; you start the [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), and you're giving the `Run` method a continuation, which it then processes.  That continuation is not channeled back in any meaningful to the code that called `Task.Run`.

This is why you get the exception, the handler doesn't *know* to [`await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) on the `Task` that the call to `Task.Run` produces.

That said:

```
private void SendUpdates()
```

Works because the task is created and the code doesn't capture a [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) (because there is no `async` keyword on the method, `Task` instances don't capture it by default).  You are firing the task, but it's fire-and-forget.

And the following works too:

```
private async Task SendUpdates()
```

Namely because in returning the `Task`, you've returned an awaitable that the callback can work with.

To answer your question directly, the compiler will make sure to get the `SynchronizationContext` returned from [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) before you call `await`; whatever continuation is called after the awaitable returns will be called using that `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: In fact, I don't want to await anything. Do you mean that when I write async Task SendUpdates(), my inner task is wrapped in a Task compatible with the ASP.NET synchronization context, but that when I call async void SendUpdates(), this wrapping doesn't happen, which explains the issue?

Comment: @Eilistraee When you write `async Task SendUpdates`, yes, the `SynchronizationContext` is captured and the `Task` that's returned is awaited on.  When you have `async void SendUpdates`, you aren't calling await on anything.  If anything, you should have at least a compiler warning indicating that you're using `async` but don't have a corresponding `await` (the `await` is on the anonymous delegate, not in the actual call code of the method).

Comment: But even in the async Task SendUpdates() case, I am not awaiting the returned task. I mean, this task reference is lost, and the OnConnectedAsync continue its execution without awaiting anything (and its a good thing as the inner task won't complete)

Comment: @Eilistraee You don't have to await the returned task, the returned task is awaited upon, whereas in the first case, there's nothing to be awaited upon, but a new task is started regardless.