# Asynchronous web service in ASP. NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asynchronous, async-await

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application which among others uses web services to get/process some the data.

The data flow of the app is  following: MVC Action -> Service B -> ExtSvc which is async wrapper of a web service

Here are some examples:

```
public class ExtSvc
{       
//Convert Event based async pattern to task based async pattern:

        private Task<Response> ProcessExtRequestAsync(Request request)
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<Response> taskCompletionSource =
                AsyncServiceClientHelpers.CreateSource<Response>(request);
            ProcessRequestCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
            handler =
                (sender, e) =>
                AsyncServiceClientHelpers.TransferCompletion(
                    taskCompletionSource, 
                    e, 
                    () => e.Result, 
                    () => this.Service.ProcessRequestCompleted -= handler);
            this.Service.ProcessRequestCompleted += handler;
            try
            {
              this.Service.ProcessRequestAsync(request, taskCompletionSource);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                this.Service.ProcessRequestCompleted -= handler;
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
                throw;
            }

                return taskCompletionSource.Task;
            }

            //Usage:

            public async Task<Response> UpdateRequest(some arguments)
            {
                //Validate arguments and create a Request object

            var response = await this.ProcessExtRequestAsync(request)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

            return response;
        }
}
```

Class B is the one that uses ExtSvc in a **synchronous** way

```
public class B
{
    public ExtSvc service {get; set;}

    public Response Update(arguments)
    {
       //some logic
       var result = this.ExtSvc.UpdateRequest(arguments).Result;
       //some logic
       return result 
    }
}
```

Finally the MVC action (also **synchronous**)

```
public ActionResult GetResponse(int id)
{
     //some logic
     B.Update(id);
     //some logic
     return View(...);
}
```

The described flow throws an error

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Web.dll
>
> Additional information: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at
>   this time.  Asynchronous operations may only be started within an
>   asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page
>   lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure
>   that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may
>   also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is
>   generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the
>   asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await
>   it.

on the following line of ExtSvc : `this.Service.ProcessRequestAsync(request, taskCompletionSource);` `ProcessRequestAsync` is a void method
So it corresponds to:

> This exception may
>   also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is
>   generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing

**I know that converting GetResponse MVC action to asynchronous (by using async/await) and also converting the B class that actually uses ExtSvc to be asynchronous resolves the issue.**

**BUT my questions is:**

If I can't change the signature of B class (because of an interface it implements) to return `Task<Response>` instead of `Response` it basically means that I can't use async/await on it so how this issue could be resolved?

Comment: You cannot change the signatures of B class (because of an interface it implements), but can you make it implement a new interfaces with `Task<T>` signatures, and use that one instead? Otherwise, you're stuck with the blocking synchronous calls; using `Task.Run` to wrap them doesn't make sense in ASP.NET.

Comment: @Alex [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c) could give you a bit more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProcessRequestAsync` is `void` but it's not `async void`. It looks like it's an [EBAP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx). EBAP components [generally use `AsyncOperationManager`/`AsyncOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228974(v=vs.110).aspx), which in turn [do use `SynchronizationContext` to notify the underlying platform of the asynchronous operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) (the last link is to my MSDN article on `SynchronizationContext`).

The exception you're seeing is because ASP.NET sees that notification (of the asynchronous operation starting) and says "whoa, there, fella. You're a *synchronous* handler! No async for you!"

Hands-down, the best approach is to make all methods asynchronous that should be asynchronous. This means `B.Update` should be `B.UpdateAsync`. OK, so there's an interface `IB.Update` - just change the interface to `IB.UpdateAsync` too. Then you're async all the way, and the code is clean.

Otherwise, you'll have to consider hacks. You could use `Task.Run` as @neleus suggested - that's a way of avoiding the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` so it doesn't "see" the asynchronous operation starting - but note that "ambient context" such as `HttpContext.Current` and page culture is lost. Or, you could (temporarily) install a `new SynchronizationContext()` onto the request thread - which also avoids the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` while staying on the same thread - but some ASP.NET calls *assume* the presence of the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` and will fail.

There's another hack you could try; it might work but I've never done it. Just make your handler return a `Task<ActionResult>` and use `Task.FromResult` to return the view: `return Task.FromResult<ActionResult>(View(...));` This hack will tell ASP.NET that your handler is asynchronous (even though it's not).

Of course, all of these hacks have the primary disadvantage that you're doing sync-over-async (`this.ExtSvc.UpdateRequest(arguments).Result`), which means you'll be using one extra unnecessary thread for the duration of each request (or *two* threads, if you use the `Task.Run` hack). So you will be missing all the benefits of using asynchronous handlers in the first place - namely, scalability.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer( and for your excellent blogs). I was aware of all the suggested approaches and your answer actually confirmes that I am not missing any reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error occurs because your code

```
this.Service.ProcessRequestAsync(request, taskCompletionSource);
```

actually calls `SynchronizationContext's` `OperationStarted` method that results in error as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13043542/2528649).

As a possible solution you can call your action on `ThreadPoolSynchronizationContext`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetResponse(int id)
{
     //some logic
     await Task.Run(() => { B.Update(id); });
     //some logic
     return View(...);
}
```

but it adds some overhead of utilizing a thread from the pool.

Comment: Using `Task.Run` in ASP.NET will cause a context switch to another thread from the thread pool (with all that can come from that, like the thread pool needing to grow or impossibility to grow) and the release of the current thread to the thread pool and again when the task is completed.

Comment: Yep, that's right but this is due to the fact that `B.Update()` is a synchronous method

Comment: @neleus, thank you for your answer. I am aware of this solution but as Paulo Morgado stated it adds unnecessary overhead and doesn't actually add any improvements in application responsiveness. If there is no other solution i think will end up using web service synchronously.